# эффекты в цикле выпонить отдельно друг от друга

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго

Ajax по определенному сценарию тащит новые данные, обновляю, все норм. Решил попробовать с эффектами сделать

```
array.forEach(function(item, i, array){
    var event_id = i;
    var event_va = item;
    $("#event_" + event_id).slideUp().delay(300).html(event_va).fadeIn(500);
});
```

грубо говоря проходимся в цикле по дивам, у них заменяются значения + эффект. Но получается странная вещь, эффекты применяются сразу для всех элементов

Вопрос прост, как оптимизировать конструкцию, что бы сначала эффект появления/исчезания был у первого элемента, после полного выполнения эффекта у второго и т.д. ?

Comment: используйте callback

Comment: прошу, примером напугайте, а то если честно не представляю как код еще и на доп функцию разбить, которую нужно вызвать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно же - глянуть документацию `jQuery`.
Методы анимации принимают `callback`, который выполнится после окончания анимации.
Метод `fadeIn` [не исключение](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B8c%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).

```js
let array = ['merry', 'christmas', 'and', 'happy', 'new', 'year'],
    show = (e, data) => e.slideUp().delay(300).html(data).fadeIn(500, () => t.next()),
    t = showMe();

function* showMe(){
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    show($("#event_" + i), array[i]);
    yield;
  }
}

t.next();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='event_0'></div>
<div id='event_1'></div>
<div id='event_2'></div>
<div id='event_3'></div>
<div id='event_4'></div>
<div id='event_5'></div>
```